# Zurmo reports (Export to CSV) painfully slow

Tags: php, crm, export-to-csv, redbean

So I have a XAMPP setup with Zurmo 2.6.5 running on it. Everything works like a charm. The speed at which it pulls up contacts, goes through pages, etc is considerably fast. I have 2 GB RAM and this is the only web app that runs on it. You can call it dedicated I guess. The problem arises when I attempt to export a fairly decent amount of data to Excel (CSV is the only option available). For e.g, I tried exporting 200-odd rows of data and it timed out due to the max_execution_limit parameter. I increased it first from around 300 to 600, and now finally to 1200. The script keeps running as though there were no end to it :-/.

Surprisingly, when I first apply the filter (not many, just one), it takes around 10-15 seconds to display the first 10 records. That indicates the query executes well within time limits. I have memcached installed, like they suggest to alleviate performance issues.

I checked Zurmo's forums and the net in general, but unfortunately I did not get even a single hit with reference to this issue. Can any fellow Zurmo developer / power user help me get this resolved?

Much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Viewed 10 times.. anyone? :-/

Comment: Are you using custom code to export your data? If you use custom code, please show us some lines of it. I have never heard of Zurmo before and I guess, that only the developers can help you to answer this question if it is a built-in functionality.